# List all files that end in "ball" using ls command

Tags: linux, ls

I am trying to use `ls` command to find specific files that

1. Have 4 letters in front of the word "ball"
2. Must have the ending word "ball"

I have been trying to use `ls *ball` but this shows words with 4 or more words in front of the word "ball". Is there a specific command that ignores the word that has 4 or more letters before "ball"?

Comment: What do you mean by _letter_? A letter in any alphabet? Only the ones in the latin script? Only without diacritics?

Comment: `ls` doesn't do any of the finding.  You're using shell wildcards.   `ls *ball` and `echo *ball` are basically the same.  Search for information about shell wildcards, also known as globbing.

Comment: You contradict yourself several times in your question. Sometimes using word, sometimes letter, implying you want 4 letters before "ball" and then saying you don't want 4 "words" before ball. Please edit your question and clarify what you want.

Answer (score 5):

If by *letter*, you mean any character that is considered *alphabetical* in your locale (that generally means any alphabet supported by your character set), you can use:

```
ls -d -- [[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]ball
```

Or with `zsh` with its `extendedglob` option:

```
ls -d -- [[:alpha:]](#c4)ball
```

or with `ksh93`:

```
ls -d -- {4}([[:alpha:]])ball
```

Note that it's the shell that expands those patterns, `ls` only lists the arguments it's being given, you could as well replace `ls -d --` with `printf '%s\n'`.

Comment: I just want to see the teacher's face when receiving this instead of ????ball

Answer (score 4):

Use `?` to match any single character:

```
ls ????ball
```

If you are interested in regular files only:

```
for i in ????ball; do [ -f "$i" ] && echo "$i"; done
```

Comment: thank you! I just thought that maybe 4 `?` was too much.

Comment: @SamPerales `?` is the way to go when you are precise about the number of characters..